# Tensor product is complete?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, gn.general-topology, tensor-products

Let $(V,\|\cdot\|_V)$ and $(W,\|\cdot\|_W)$ be Banach spaces and let the norm $\|\cdot\|_{V\otimes W}$ on the tensor product space $V\otimes W$ be admissible in the following sense: for $v\in V, w\in W$,

(1) the norm is symmetric, in the sense that $\|v\otimes w \|_{V\otimes W}= \|w\otimes v\|\\\\$.

(2) the norm satisfies: $\|v\otimes w \|_{V\otimes W}\leq \|v\|_{W} \cdot \|w\|_V$.

Is it true that the tensor product space ($V\otimes W$, $\|\cdot\|_{V\otimes W}$) will thus be complete (and thus Banach)?

Comment: Let's assume both V and W are infinite dimensional. Injective tensor product and projective tensor product are the very first examples that comes to mind for which $V\otimes W$ is not complete.

Comment: In fact, it's hard to think of *any* examples where the algebraic tensor product $V\otimes W$ is complete. Conjecture: if $V$ and $W$ are both infinite dimensional, then $V\otimes W$ is not complete.

Comment: Good idea ... is the set of rank $\leq r$ tensors closed? I guess this would do it.

Comment: A suggestion to show that the result is false if both spaces are infinite dimensional.  One can find norm one linearly independent sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$. The series $\Sigma \frac 1 {n^2}x_n \otimes y_n$ converges in the completion but the limit is not in the algebraic tensor product.

Comment: @terceira it sure doesn't look like it could be in the algebraic tensor product, but can you prove this?

Comment: I have rereread the question multiple times and there is something I don't get: what could it mean to say $||v \otimes w||_{V \otimes W} = ||w \otimes v||$ when $V$ and $W$ are not the same space?  The elementary tensor $w \otimes v$ doesn't live in $V \otimes W$, so the right side of that equation doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Yes, the symmetry requirement only works for copies of the same $V$ tensored with each other. This is an oversight

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ or $W$ finite-dimensional, then $V \otimes W$ consists of sums $$\sum_{j=1}^n v_j\otimes w_j\tag1$$ with a fixed number $n$ of terms.

But when $V,W$ are infinite-dimensional, you have sums $\sum_{j=1}^n v_j\otimes w_j$ with unbounded $n$.

Surely partial sums of $\sum_{j=1}^\infty v_j\otimes w_j$ would be Cauchy in  $V \otimes W$ provided $\sum \|v_j\|_V\;\|w_j\|_W < \infty$, but there is no reason to think such a sum would be expressed as a finite sum $(1)$.